# Is $D^k$ open in $\bigsqcup_{i=1}^nD^i$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to solve an exercise and I would need the fact that the disk of dimension $k$, $D^k$, is open in $\bigsqcup_{i=1}^nD^i$. Is it true?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: $1\leq k \leq n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of the topology of the disjoint union, the image of $A$ is open in $A \sqcup B$: it is open in itself, and its intersection with the image of $B$ is empty (which is open).